# what are the possible values for IContainerGroup.State property? using azure sdk for container groups in azure

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-sdk

I am using azure SDK for management and I have the following code. I am wondering what are the possible values for `IContainerGroup.State` ? I am using the code below and so far i can find two values `"Running"` and `"Succeeded"` I am looking for other possible values which the documentation does not provide.

```
containerGroup = azure.ContainerGroups.GetByResourceGroup(rgName, aciName);
console.log($"Container State Is: { containerGroup.State }");
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be 5 possible values for `containerGroup.State`:

- **Running:** The container group is running and will continue to try to run until a user action or a stop caused by the restart policy occurs.
- **Stopped:** The container group has been stopped and will not be scheduled to run without user action.
- **Pending:** The container group is waiting to initialize (finish running init containers, mount Azure file volumes if applicable). The container continues to attempt to get to the **Running** state unless a user action (stop/delete) happens.
- **Succeeded:** The container group has run to completion successfully. Only applicable for *Never* and *On Failure* restart policies.
- **Failed:** The container group failed to run to completion. Only applicable with a *Never* restart policy. This state indicates either an infrastructure failure (example: incorrect Azure file share credentials) or user application failure (example: application references an environment variable that does not exist).

The following table shows what states are applicable to a container group based on the designated restart policy:
[image]

For more information please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-state#container-groups).